# Angular how to change datetime format in input value attribute

Tags: angular

I have input with value of datetime-local and I need to change the format and display the time but it's not working

```
<div class="col-md-6 p-2">
    <h5 class="fw-bold color-main">Collection Date</h5>
    <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" disabled class="form-control"
    [value]="{{ collect_date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a' }}">
</div>
```

It gives me this error `Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[] and {{}} are never used together.{{}} is for string interpolation only.

Use value as below

```
[value]="collect_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a'"
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tefeqa?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

when wrapping your directive name with [square brackets] you can not use
{{double curly brackets}} for its value,

you can either put it like this:

**value="{{ collect_date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a' }}"**

or like this:

**[value]="collect_date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a'"**